# Integers Appear as PY_VAR0 in a .txt document

Tags: python, tkinter

For my GCSEs I have taking a computing course and one of my tasks was to make a 'Character Attribute Creator'. I basically made one in Tkinter using a .txt file to create a character and display a name, age, skill and strength.

The problem I encounter is when I add the `Skill` and `Strength` variables to the text file (using this code: `myfile.write("Name: "+mEntry1.get()+", Age: "+mEntry2.get()+", Skill: "+str(x)+", Strength: "+str(v))`. The x and v variables are printed to the .txt document as `PY_VAR0` and `PY_VAR1`.

Here is my full code:

```
///

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Import
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox
import random
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Program
mGui = Tk()
mGui.geometry("300x300")
mGui.title("Character Attribrute Setter")
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Definitions...
x = IntVar()
v = IntVar()
x.set(0)
v.set(0)
# Decides Skill... random.randint()
def mStren():
    y = random.randint(1,12)
    c = random.randint(1,4)
    v = y/c
# Decides Strength... random.randint()
def mSkill():
    a = random.randint(1,12)
    b = random.randint(1,4)
    x = a/b
# How it Works... tkMessageBox() (mMb1)
def mMB1():
    mMB1 = tkMessageBox.showinfo(title="How it works",message="PLEASE ENTER ALL                  INFORMATION AND PRESS BOTH SIMULATE BUTTONS! The aim of this program is to determine a characters Strength and Skill. It does this by setting two Integers to 10. After that, a 12 sided die is rolled, after that, a 4 sided die is rolled. The outcome of the 12 sided die is divided by the outcome of the 4 sided die. This total is then added to the Integers, thus determining Skill and Strength.")
# Create... Save to a .txt file (mC1)
def mC1():
    myfile = open("Character.txt", "w")
    myfile.write("Name: "+mEntry1.get()+", Age: "+mEntry2.get()+", Skill: "+str(x)+", Strength: "+str(v))
    myfile.close()
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Welcome... Label (mLabel1)
mLabel1 = Label(text="Welcome to: Character Attribute Setter!")
mLabel1.pack()
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Created By... Label (mLabel2)
mLabel2 = Label(text="Created By: Harry Spicer.")
mLabel2.pack()
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# How it works... Button (mButton1)
mButton1 = Button(text="How it works",command=mMB1)
mButton1.place(x=0,y=275)
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Please enter your name... Label (mlabel3)
mLabel3 = Label(text="Please enter your name:")
mLabel3.place(x=0,y=75)
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Please enter your Age... Label (mlabel4)
mLabel3 = Label(text="Please enter your Age:")
mLabel3.place(x=0,y=175)
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Name... Entry (mEntry1)
mEntry1 = Entry()
mEntry1.place(x=0,y=100)
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Age... Entry (mEntry1)
mEntry2 = Entry()
mEntry2.place(x=0,y=200)
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Create... Button (mButton2)
mButton2 = Button(text="Create Character",command=mC1)
mButton2.pack()
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Simulate Skill... Button (mButton3)
mButton3 = Button(text="Simulate Skill",command=mSkill)
mButton3.pack()
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Simulate Skill... Button (mButton4)
mButton4 = Button(text="Simulate Strength",command=mStren)
mButton4.pack()
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Mainloop
mGui.mainloop()
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
///
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x` and `v` are `IntVar`'s.  You need to invoke the `.get` method on each of them:

```
myfile.write("Name: "+mEntry1.get()+", Age: "+mEntry2.get()+", Skill: "+str(x.get())+", Strength: "+str(v.get()))
```

Doing so will return their values as integers.

Without this, all you have are references to the variables themselves, not their values.

Also, you can write that line in a better way like this:

```
myfile.write("Name: {}, Age: {}, Skill: {}, Strength: {}".format(mEntry1.get(), mEntry2.get(), x.get(), v.get()))
```

This method, which uses [`str.format`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format), is more efficient and easier to work with.

Comment: @HarrySpicer Happy to help!  Don't forget to accept my answer (click the tick) to let people know this problem is solved.